# discord.py logs_from not working

Tags: python, discord.py

i am trying to get a lot of messages from a server, so i am making a test scripts, and the logs_from() is not working how i think it should, i dont know if im using it wrong or what, i am using python 3.5, and the most recent version of discord.py on pypi

```
@client.event
@asyncio.coroutine
def on_message(message):
    number = 200
    x = client.logs_from(message.channel, limit = number)
    print(x[1])
```

and i get the error

```
TypeError: 'LogsFromIterator' object does not support indexing
```

Comment: Is your intention to get the very first entry resulting from `logs_from`, or the second one?

Comment: eventually get all of them, but it isnt getting any of them right now, it doesnt matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Client.logs_from`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logs_from) is a coroutine, meaning you must first await it. It also returns an iterator, not a list, so you should iterate through it, instead of indexing it.

Python 3.5 example:

```
async def get_logs_from(channel):
    async for m in client.logs_from(channel):
        print(m.clean_content)
```

Python 3.4 example:

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def get_logs_from(channel):
    logs = yield from client.logs_from(channel):
    for m in logs:
        print(m.clean_content)
```